# spark job unable to Execute in yarn-cluster mode

Tags: pyspark

I am using Spark version 1.6.0 , Python version 2.6.6

I have a pyspark script as:

```
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("Log Analysis")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

loadFiles=sc.wholeTextFiles("hdfs:///locations")

fileWiseData=loadFiles.flatMap(lambda inpFile : inpFile[1].split("\n\n"))
replaceNewLine=fileWiseData.map(lambda lines:lines.replace("\n",""))
filterLines=replaceNewLine.map(lambda lines:lines.replace("/"," ")) 
errorEntries =filterLines.filter(lambda errorLines : "Error" in errorLines) 

errEntry= errorEntries.map(lambda line: gettingData(line))#formatting the data 

ErrorFiltered = Row('ExecutionTimeStamp','ExecutionDate','ExecutionTime','ExecutionEpoch','ErrorNum','Message')
errorData = errEntry.map(lambda r: ErrorFiltered(*r))

errorDataDf = sqlContext.createDataFrame(errorData)
```

`
when i am executing the script after splitting my 1gb log file into 20mb(in general , or for 30,40..mbs splits of the files), the script part is working fine .

```
  spark-submit --jars /home/hpuser/LogAnaysisPOC/packages/spark-csv_2.10-1.5.0.jar,/home/hpuser/LogAnaysisPOC/packages/commons-csv-1.1.jar \
--master yarn-cluster --driver-memory 6g --executor-memory 6g --conf spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead=4096 \
--conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=4096 \
/home/user/LogAnaysisPOC/scripts/essbase/Essbaselog.py
```

1) if i try to execute with 1gb as the input ,once ,it's failing(errorDataDf = sqlContext.createDataFrame(errorData)).

2) I need to join the parsed data with one meta-data data-frame which is shuffling  around 43mb. `dfinal.repartition(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").save("/user/user/loganalysis")`

again it's working fine for splited data and failing for the data at once.

The job execution is failing with error :
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit

The Yarn scheduler setting are as follows:

```
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.queues=default,hive1,hive2
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.user-limit-factor=1
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.state=RUNNING
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.maximum-capacity=100
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.capacity=50
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.acl_submit_applications=*
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.capacity=100
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.acl_administer_queue=*
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.accessible-node-labels=*
yarn.scheduler.capacity.node-locality-delay=40
yarn.scheduler.capacity.maximum-applications=10000
yarn.scheduler.capacity.maximum-am-resource-percent=0.5
yarn.scheduler.capacity.queue-mappings-override.enable=false
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.minimum-user-limit-percent=25
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.ordering-policy=fifo
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.hive1.acl_administer_queue=*
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.hive1.acl_submit_applications=*
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.hive1.capacity=25
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.hive1.maximum-capacity=100
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.hive1.minimum-user-limit-percent=25
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.hive1.ordering-policy=fifo
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.hive1.state=RUNNING
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.hive1.user-limit-factor=1
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.hive2.acl_administer_queue=*
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.hive2.acl_submit_applications=*
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.hive2.capacity=25
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.hive2.maximum-capacity=100
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.hive2.minimum-user-limit-percent=25
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.hive2.ordering-policy=fifo
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.hive2.state=RUNNING
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.hive2.user-limit-factor=1
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.user-limit-factor=1
```

[cluster details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uLed.png)

i have asked the same question in the [forum](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/168877/spark-job-unable-to-execute-in-yarn-cluster-mode.html)

Any  form of suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please format your code *blocks* properlym and not as inline code segments...

Comment: --driver-memory 3g --executor-memory 3g --conf spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead=3076  --conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=4096.


Do you have that much memory free in your system? It looks like yarn is unable to allocate the requested memory and hence failing

Comment: @HarshBafna , Thanks , i have updated the statement , when i am executing the script after splitting my 1gb log file into 20mb splits, the script part is working fine but for 1 gb at once  it's failing . i am doing this in poc cluster of 3 node having 39GB memory .